# Socket.IO socket.id changing for same client without reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm making an application where I need to map sockets to some object. I thought I would be safe using the socket.id variable provided by Socket.IO. Unfortunately while debugging I found out that the socket.id changed without the client disconnecting/reconnecting or whatever.

Here's a small piece of code to show what I'm trying to do:

```
var io         = require('socket.io').listen(8080),
var myVariable = new Array();

// Main event loop
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('myEvent', function(data) {
        myVariable[socket.id] = data;
    }
    // 'someOtherEvent' which uses the mapped data.
    socket.on('someOtherEvent', function(data) {
        // Doesn't always work because socket.id has changed and var is empty
        doSomethingWith(myVariable[socket.id]);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure but I don't think this is the desired effect. Why does this happen and how would I work around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/) to debug my application and because I was holding the code on some breakpoint it disconnected the client (probably some timeout client side). That's why I got a new socket.id when I continued the code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'someOtherEvent' emited before 'myEvent' or socket has been reconnected. I use socket.id as connection identifier on two different projects in production and it works without any problems.

Comment: That's not it. The code example might not've been clear enough but there's just one event firing which does stuff with the socket.id. The big issue is that with the same client, without reconnecting the socket.id changes.